# Python short hand for simultaneous initializations?

Tags: python

Lets say I have parent class -"Parent" and I want to create three objects - o1,o2,o3 from this.

So if there a short hand or a beautiful way of doing the following:

```
o1=Parent()
o2=Parent()
o3=Parent()
```

Comment: at least I would prefer all the initializations in a single line. Though that would still not meet my expectations, but I can live with that. Ideally 'o1,o2,o3 = Parent()' should have worked.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, consider accepting it. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's more beautiful is a matter of opinion, but you could do it in one line, like this:

```
o1, o2, o3 = Parent(), Parent(), Parent()
```

Note, however, that the following does *not* work, as it assigns the same object to each variable:

```
o1 = o2 = o3 = Parent() # does NOT work!
```

You could also use a list comprehension or generator expression to create three instances and use list unpacking to assign them to the different variables:

```
o1, o2, o3 = (Parent() for _ in range(3))
```

This may seem a bit complicated at first, but is probably the best solution if the initialization of the `Parent` is more complex, e.g. if you are passing some parameters, too.

You might be tempted to use list multiplication, but again, this would not work as the list would hold three references to the same object.

```
o1, o2, o3 = [Parent()] * 3 # does NOT work, too!
```

Comment: I can live with your first suggestion, but would have preferred if the second could have worked ...:)

Comment: FWIW, since we're not using the values produced by `range(3)`, we could use a shorter alternative like `for _ in [0]*3`, which avoids a function call. And since the number of items desired is constant we could simply iterate over a constant string, eg `'123'` or `'...'`, which avoids the multiplication (and compiles to less bytecode).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you require exactly. If you simply want to create three `Parent` objects you can generate a tuple:

```
objs = tuple(Parent() for _ in xrange(3))
```

and access the objects as `objs[0]`, `objs[1]` and `objs[2]`.

If you really want them to be named `o1`, `o2` and `o3`, then you can unpack the tuple thus:

```
o1, o2, o3 = (Parent() for _ in xrange(3))
```

Note that this is largely equivalent to the following:

```
o1, o2, o3 = Parent(), Parent(), Parent()
```

The drawback of the second and third methods is that you must ensure that the number of elements in the tuples on the LHS and RHS match.